# find triple integral $\iiint_V (3x^{2}+2y+z) dxdydz$

Tags: integration, multiple-integral, change-of-variable

find triple integral $\iiint_V (3x^{2}+2y+z )dxdydz$ where
$\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
|x-y| \le 1 \\ 
|y-z| \le 1 \\ 
|x+z| \le1
\end{array}
\right.$

I try to change variables $x-y=u,y-z=v,x+z=w$ but I have problem with showing function $3x^2+2y+z$ in variables u,v,w.

Can you guys help me with this problem/exercise ? Thank u so much

Comment: Try adding or subtracting different combinations of $u$s, $v$s, and $w$s, and see what happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x-y=u$, $y-z=v$, and $x+z=w$, then$$x=\frac{u+v+w}2,\ y=\frac{-u+v+w}2,\text{ and }z=\frac{-u-v+w}2,$$and therefore$$3x^2+2y+z=\frac{3 u^2+6 v u+6 w u-6 u+3 v^2+3 w^2+2 v+6 v w+6 }4.$$On the other hand, the Jacobian of the map$$(u,v,w)\mapsto\left(\frac{u+v+w}2,\frac{-u+v+w}2,\frac{-u-v+w}2\right)$$is constant and equal to $\frac12$. Therefore, your integral is equal to$$\int_{-1}^1\int_{-1}^1\int_{-1}^1\frac{3 u^2+6 v u+6 w u-6 u+3 v^2+3 w^2+2 v+6 v w+6 }8\,\mathrm dw\,\mathrm dv\,\mathrm du.$$

Comment: thank you so muchh

Comment: I'm glad I could help.